# Columns to have 100% height in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

If you go to my website: [website](http://bravocreations.com/wp/)
you see the top black line that's the header. The bottom black line is the footer. 
The middle section is the content , in side the content I did columns.  Now what I am trying to do is make the footer sticky to the bottom of the page without the scroller to appear. Then I am trying to make the columns go down to the footer. But not by changing the min height to higher. I want the columns to always go do to the footer.  So that the column background will be all the way down to the footer.

Here is the pic of what i need [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqqx6.jpg)

Here is my css and html

```
html,body {
height:100%;}
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 157%;
color: #666666;
padding:0;

}
.content {
min-height: 0;
background-color: #9E959E;
height: calc(100% - 50px); /* add this */ }

.footer {
min-height: 25px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#000000;
clear: both;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
}

.header {
min-height:300px;
background-color:#000000;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
.header {
    min-height: 25px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
.header {
    min-height: 25px;
}
}



<body>
<div class="header">
</div>  <div class="content">
<div class="page-content">
<div class="column_4"></div>
<div class="column_5"></div>
<div class="column_6"></div>
<div class="column_7"></div>
</div>  </div>
<div class="footer">
</div>      <div style="display:none">
</div></body>
```

Comment: please remove the jquery tag and just do a search on SO for the answer first - I have found 15 answers just by typing 'full height column' into the search box

Comment: i did for a full day yesterday and i can get none to work right.

Comment: sigh - people really do not want to read - add `height: 100%` to .page-content and for each column add `height: 100%` - it would be easier to give all columns a class of 'fullHeight' and then write a separate class - you are using classes like Ids

Comment: i tried the do that in  .content and in content child  but still no luck.

Comment: Quick question, how is this a Wordpress problem?

Comment: i did this template in WP Builder.   its not a wordpress problem , its wordpress related.

Answer (score 0):

I found this CSS in your website: http://bravocreations.com/wp/wp-content/themes/WordPress-Site7/page.css?ver=4.1.1

You might want to consider changing the height properties to e.g. 100% from those 600px and 700px

You might also want to install FireBug, so you can find CSS responsible for such issues quickly

as the code is quite lenghty I put it on the pastebin

http://pastebin.com/LMPZ4Hjy

Comment: i did that and then the columns disappear .

Comment: any one with a solution ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Hello 50% i mean, the column went down but i have a scroller showing up. can i have it without a scroller.  Thank You

Comment: redCodeAlert Thank You very much. i fix it by adding overflow:hidden to body.